# LED Strip Power Supply needs to be unplugged/replugged to work

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I bought a color changing LED light kit for my basement and found out it wasn't long enough so I bought another. I connected them together with an LED amplifier and it seemed to work perfectly. Except when I came back the next day to turn them on again, they didn't work. I found that I needed to unplug the PS and re-plug it and viola, the lights worked again. This happens every time now when I want to turn them on. I've replaced the PS with a spare and it's the same results. I'll mention that disconnecting the PS from the LED controller does not fix it, it has to be unplugged from the outlet to fix it. Anyone know where I might be going wrong?

Here is my PS
[image: PS]

And my LED controller
[image: controller]

And amplifier
[image: amp]

[image: Wiring Diagram]

Here are some links to the components I used:

[AMP PS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06X8Z7NJL)

[AMP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MN7AFLC)

[Splitter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01G7X9QZS)

Comment: How did you wire it?

Comment: @Harper, The controller connects to the amp input, then I have a splitter coming off the amp that connects the 2 led strips.

Comment: You can't just give a one-sentence  tossie, you need to give a lot more information than that, or none of us will be able to help you.   Diagram the whole thing out, every wire, and post a pic.

Comment: I included a diagram as best I could and links to some of the components I used.

Comment: Oh MUCH better!

Comment: sounds like it's over-heating to me.

Comment: @dandavis, Thanks for your input.  Do you know how I can check that?  Also, why would it overheat while the lights are turned off?  I know it would still draw power for the IR receiver but it doesn't overheat if I have the lights on for several hours.

Comment: it's the only thing i can think that would enable unplugging from the wall to fix it, but not unplugging the controller w/o the wall adapter.

Answer (score 1):

OK here's the problem.  An *amplifier* does not actually combine power supplies.  It simply uses the 5 input channels *only as a signal* to switch the power supplied to its input.  All the strips downstream of an amplifier are powered *only* by the supply to the amplifier!

So what you've done is hung *all* the LEDs on the #2 power supply, which is only sized for a single 16' (5m) strip.

The other power supply drives nothing but the controller and amplifier's internal loads, which are very small.  That might be a problem too.

Option 1, leave it like this, and make sure power supply #2 is sized to drive *all* LEDs. I don't get why to have supply #1 at that point, just split power off supply #2 and do it all with one.

Option 2:

Move the splitter so it takes the output of the *controller* and splits it to *strip 1* and *the amplifier*.   Thus, power supply 1 will supply the controller and strip 1.    Power supply 2 will supply only the amplifier and strip 2.

[image]

Comment: I would agree with you but its just the opposite, the PS feeding the controller is the one that stops working and needs to be unplugged not the PS feeding the AMP.  The controller is rated for 2A which will power a single strip, the AMP provides 6A which should power 3 strips, I only have it powering 2.

Comment: @PrestonS different problem then, that power supply is crowbar'ing because it has *no load at all*.  Either way, the setup ain't right.  A 2A supply can only power about 5' of RGBW strip at full brightness with all lights blazing.

Comment: It came as a kit. The 2A PS, controller and single 5M strip. I bought 2 of them and combined them together.

Comment: Wouldn't the 2A PS always deliver some load due to the IR receiver?  What do you mean by "crowbar'ing"

Comment: I just noticed where power supply #2 already is 6 amps.  That's good for about 15' of strip at full brightness. A crowbar is when a power supply shuts itself down because some supply parameter is out of bounds, too much current, too little current, etc.  The IR receiver/controller will take a ridiculously tiny amount of power, and that could trip it. Or the unit could be bum. Anyway, why have 2 for the tiny amount of load on PS 1, just fork off PS 2.

Comment: That sounds more likely, I used both PS because I didnt wont to bother tearing them down to wire up with a single PS, it has the standard barrel adapter on it so it's not straight forward to power both devices.  Any suggestions on how to connect two devices to one PS?

Comment: @PrestonS lots of people sell power splitters. I'm still puzzled at how you can power so much strip with such small supplies, check the numbers carefully but if your supplies are undersized it'll work til you turn it up too bright.